# Creating an element with 'class' attribute throws a syntax error

Tags: python, lxml

When I try to do this with the `lxml` module:

```
div = etree.SubElement(body, "div", class="hmi")
```

I get a:

```
user@localhost:metk $ sudo python mbscan.py -r 192.168.0.0/24 --hmi
  File "mbscan.py", line 481
    div = etree.SubElement(body, "div", class="hmi")
                                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Because class is a keyword reserved for Python for another use. IE this:

```
div = etree.SubElement(body, "div", hello="hmi")
```

works fine.

I know there is another engine made specifically for `html` in `lxml` but for the sake of keeping my `xml` and `html` report generators as similar as possible I'm wondering if there isn't another workaround here?

**How can I create an `xml` tag with a `class` attribute without upsetting Python?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a dictionary of attributes and pass it as `attrib` argument.

For example:

```
>>> from lxml.html import Element, tostring
>>> 
>>> div = Element("div", attrib={"class": "hmi"})
>>> 
>>> print(tostring(div))
<div class="hmi"></div>
```

Note that I'm using `lxml.html` here, but the same idea applies for `etree`.